# Netbeans with Java how to find the source of an error?

Tags: java, debugging, netbeans

I use Netbeans for my Java IDE.  I am building off a 3rd party API.  I have built quite a bit on top of it.  I try to leave good debugging messages around my code, but I am getting a very basic error message, then my program is closing.  I get this `Error - java.io.EOFException` and then shortly after the program closes.  I think it is just a system output printed line showing the error coming from the API.

Does anyone know of a technique in Netbeans of Java in general where I could identify where the error is coming from?

Comment: Are you getting a stack trace? Or just the error with no clues?

Comment: try{your code}catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();} or use IDE to debug..

Comment: I am just getting the text that I have in the question above printed to the text output.

Comment: Show us an MCVE code, the problem is somewhere in the API. It is throwing an EOF exception.

Comment: Yes thank you I will try to make an example.  If I could make the example, then I could probably identify the problem myself.  This is question is just asking if the community knows of any good tools to help me identify where the problem is coming from inside a large program.  I used the "Find in Projects..." search and searched for "Error - ", as I figured that was a generic part of the message.  And I found a few spots in the API where that msg is printed to the output.  So now I am narrowing down where the problem is coming from.  Would a stack trace do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One can put a break point on the constructor for EOFException().

To do so:

1. From the menu select Window -> Debugging -> Breakpoints or (Alt+Shift+5)
2. In the Breakpoints window, right click for pop-up and choose `New Breakpoint ...`
3. Set Breakpoint Type to Method
4. Set classname to java.io.EOFException, for convenience click the All Methods for given class checkbox. (otherwise you would have to set different breakpoints for the different constructors)
5. Choose Run -> Debug Project (Ctrl+F5) to debug your program. It should stop when the EOFException is created.
6. Go to Window -> Debugging -> Call Stack to see where it was called from.

Comment: I really like that.  I will come back to this and try it in the future.  You wouldn't believe it the next day I fired up my computer and went to work, and the glitch just wasn't there anymore...

Comment: OK the problem started showing up again.  This is a socket client program so I think that something happens with the data exchange which works sometimes and not others depending on the data.  Anyways this method is exactly what I was looking for!  Really great tool!